# Individual node colors in TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph[circular placement,
        empty nodes, nodes={circle,draw, minimum size=0.01cm}] {
    \foreach \x in {a,...,c} {
       \foreach \y in {\x,...,c} {
        \x -- \y;
      };
    };
  };
    \draw (a) edge[red, thick] (b);
    \draw (b) edge[red, thick] (c);
    \draw (c) edge[blue, thick] (a);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces a complete graph with the edges colored red/blue. I want to color node (a) blue and (b), (c) red. Or some other configuration. I can use the `fill=red!30` in the `nodes={}` area, but this causes all of the nodes to be red. How can I specify a single node?

In general, is there a way to fill color a specific node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[counterclockwise=6,
        empty nodes, nodes={circle,draw, minimum size=0.01cm}] {
a[fill=blue],  b[fill=red], c[fill=red]
  };
\draw (a) edge[red, thick] (b);
\draw (b) edge[red, thick] (c);
\draw (c) edge[blue, thick] (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost, but this seems "hard coded" for $K_{3}$ and I also only care about the fill color of the nodes. Is there no way to do something like '\node (a) fill=red!30' ? I also have much large graphs where I want to fill color individual nodes.

Comment: @Ozera If you just want to fill, add only `fill=red` in the node options.

Comment: Oh wow so it is simply `a[fill=red]` if I want to fill color the node `(a)` red! Thank you.

Comment: @TorbjornT., your solution work only with LuaLaTeX. However, if you not use library `graphdrawing`, your solution also work in pgfLaTeX. Also `--` before node `b` and `->` before node `c` seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: @Zarko Meant to remove those, were left over from testing, thanks. You're also right about `graphdrawing`, I'm just not that familiar with these kinds of things (not something I've ever needed), so I don't know exactly which libraries are needed. I removed that library.

Comment: @TorbjornT.,, you are right, I disorder something. I will erase this my comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a conditional `fill` for your convenience. For the first node only you should add `\x[fill={\ifnum\i=1 blue\else white\fi}]`, but for all other nodes, you can add `\y[fill={\ifnum\j=2 red\else\ifnum\j=3 red\else white\fi\fi}]`. Sure, you can choose any number of desired nodes individually.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph[circular placement,
        empty nodes, nodes={circle,draw, minimum size=0.01cm}] {
    \foreach \x[count=\i] in {a,...,c} {
      \foreach \y[count=\j] in {\x,...,c} {
        \x[fill={\ifnum\i=1 blue\else white\fi}] -- \y[fill={\ifnum\j=2 red\else\ifnum\j=3 red\else white\fi\fi}];
        };
      };
    };
    \draw (a) edge[red, thick] (b);
    \draw (b) edge[red, thick] (c);
    \draw (c) edge[blue, thick] (a);   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah this is also great information! Thank you for taking the time to help me answer my question.