# How to draw a network of nodes in latex like below?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

[image]

this is the network of fifteen nodes. I don't know how to draw using latex. I tried the following code for five nodes.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[counterclockwise=6,
        nodes, nodes={circle,draw, minimum size=0.01cm}] {
1,  2, 4, 3, 5
  };
\draw[->] (1) edge[black, thick] (2);
\draw[->] (1) edge[black, thick] (3);
\draw[->] (2) edge[black, thick] (4);
\draw[->] (4) edge[black, thick] (2);
\draw[->] (3) edge[black, thick] (4);
\draw[->] (3) edge[black, thick] (5);
\draw[->] (5) edge[black, thick] (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Something to get you started: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276050/36296

Comment: Your previous questions already contain most of the elements you need for this picture.

Comment: This site is not meant to be a human-powered scribble-to-Ti*k*Z conversion tool. Please try to come up with some code. This makes it much easier to help, since it makes more clear which tools you want to use and in which context you want to use the resulting code. If you tried something, you should post it and specify where you got stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am a beginner using tikz to draw a network. I struggling to put the nodes in pentagon like structure and then all three pentagons connected with each other. I tried the first answer for this question but I am unable to place the nodes in pentagone like structure.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, I completed the code using "scope". See below

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\graph[counterclockwise=5,
        nodes, nodes={circle,draw, minimum size=0.01cm}] {
1[fill = pink],  2, 4, 5, 3
  };
\draw[->] (1) edge[black, thick] (2);
\draw[->] (1) edge[black, thick] (3);
\draw[->] (2) edge[black, thick] (4);
\draw[->] (4) edge[black, thick] (2);
\draw[->] (3) edge[black, thick] (4);
\draw[->] (3) edge[black, thick] (5);
\draw[->] (5) edge[black, thick] (3);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(3,0)}]
\graph[counterclockwise=5,
        nodes, nodes={circle,draw, minimum size=0.01cm}] {
6,  7, 9, 10, 8
  };
\draw[->] (6) edge[black, thick] (7);
\draw[->] (6) edge[black, thick] (8);
\draw[->] (9) edge[black, thick] (7);
\draw[->] (8) edge[black, thick] (9);
\draw[->] (9) edge[black, thick] (10);
\draw[->] (10) edge[black, thick] (8);
\draw[->] (8) edge[black, thick] (6);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(1.5,-3)}]
\graph[counterclockwise=5,
        nodes, nodes={circle,draw, minimum size=0.01cm}] {
11,  12, 14, 15, 13
  };
\draw[->] (11) edge[black, thick] (13);
\draw[->] (12) edge[black, thick] (11);
\draw[->] (14) edge[black, thick] (12);
\draw[->] (11) edge[black, thick] (14);
\draw[->] (14) edge[black, thick] (15);
\draw[->] (15) edge[black, thick] (13);
\end{scope}
\draw[-latex] (1) -- (6);
\draw[-latex] (9) -- (11);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: +1 This is great. You should complete the code with `\documentclass`, packages and `\end{document}` both in questions and answers. This makes it *so much* easier for people who wants to help or people seeking information. All code should run by copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

I added this code in front of the snippet above:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
```

and this below it:

```
\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image: Network of Nodes]

And here's the complete listing, to make it easy for others:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \graph[counterclockwise=5,
    nodes, nodes={circle,draw, minimum size=0.01cm}] {
      1[fill = pink],  2, 4, 5, 3
    };
    \draw[->] (1) edge[black, thick] (2);
    \draw[->] (1) edge[black, thick] (3);
    \draw[->] (2) edge[black, thick] (4);
    \draw[->] (4) edge[black, thick] (2);
    \draw[->] (3) edge[black, thick] (4);
    \draw[->] (3) edge[black, thick] (5);
    \draw[->] (5) edge[black, thick] (3);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(3,0)}]
    \graph[counterclockwise=5,
    nodes, nodes={circle,draw, minimum size=0.01cm}] {
      6,  7, 9, 10, 8
    };
    \draw[->] (6) edge[black, thick] (7);
    \draw[->] (6) edge[black, thick] (8);
    \draw[->] (9) edge[black, thick] (7);
    \draw[->] (8) edge[black, thick] (9);
    \draw[->] (9) edge[black, thick] (10);
    \draw[->] (10) edge[black, thick] (8);
    \draw[->] (8) edge[black, thick] (6);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(1.5,-3)}]
    \graph[counterclockwise=5,
    nodes, nodes={circle,draw, minimum size=0.01cm}] {
      11,  12, 14, 15, 13
    };
    \draw[->] (11) edge[black, thick] (13);
    \draw[->] (12) edge[black, thick] (11);
    \draw[->] (14) edge[black, thick] (12);
    \draw[->] (11) edge[black, thick] (14);
    \draw[->] (14) edge[black, thick] (15);
    \draw[->] (15) edge[black, thick] (13);
  \end{scope}
  \draw[-latex] (1) -- (6);
  \draw[-latex] (9) -- (11);
  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```